# Do I always need to be running my Parse Server app on my server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, parse-server

I'm trying to setup a parse server on my server but am a complete noob. I've got everything installed (Node v7.8, NPM v4.4.4) on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine. I've tried to use the parse server example app as my base because I figured that'd be the safest bet.

SO, when I'm SSH'd into the server and `npm start` the app, everything works and I can `POST`and `GET` from my remote code with no problems, but when I stop the parse app, it get a `Cannot connect to the server` error. Does this mean the app always has to be running?? Seems like a waste of CPU time if the calls to the parse app are infrequent. Or have I misunderstood everything?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parse-server to answer, yes, it has to be running!  Not only that, but you want to have some kind of process manager make sure that it is always running, so that if it does happen to die, it'll get restarted for you.   Here's a popular one you can use: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

You really don't need to worry about the cpu usage.  If it aint doing nothing, it'll happily sit their blocked doing nothing, including not using cpu.  It will have a memory footprint, but that'll get swapped out if there is any memory pressure on the box.

So get it running and leave it running and don't worry about it ;).